# Antd add inital Values to dynamic form from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, antd

I want to take some data from firebase real time db and add them as the inital value for a dynamic form

```
              get(child(dbRef, `links/${dummy.prefix}/links/links`)).then((snapshot) => {
          
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                  const dummy = snapshot.val();
                  setAlllinks(dummy)
                  for(var i in dummy){
                    setTheArray([...theArray, { "links" : [dummy[i]['first'], dummy[i]['last'] ]}]);
                  }
          
                } else {
                  console.log("No data available");
                }
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
              });
```

This is the data that i get from firebase and add it to thearray

```
[
  {
    "first": "https://google.com",
    "last": "google"
  }
]
```

[image]

```
  const availablelinks = {

    links: theArray
  };
  const itemInputs = availablelinks.links.map((item) => {
    return {
      first: item.first,
      last: item.last,
    };
  });
```

for more details please see the git repo[here](https://github.com/LikeWho54/linklyftnewdash/blob/main/pages/links.js#L184)

Comment: You can have a look at the [antd form documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/). Especially the properties `value` and `setFieldsValue` might be interesting in your case

Answer (score 1):

As long as your `FormItem` components have the `name` prop (I'm not sure if it's a required or optional prop in `antd` forms), you can set the initial values for the form items using `initialValues` prop of the `Form` component itself. For example, you can see this example form:

```
<Form
  name="basic"
  initialValues={{
    username: 'Hello',
    password: 'demo',
  }}>
  <Form.Item
    label="Username"
    name="username"
>
    <Input />
  </Form.Item>

  <Form.Item
    label="Password"
    name="password"
    >
    <Input.Password />
  </Form.Item>
</Form>;
```

Please make sure that the `name` prop of the field matches what you have in the `initialValues` prop. As far as, `how to do it for a dynamic form` is concerned, you can use the `useState` hook like this:

```
const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState();
```

and then when you get the data, you can update the state using `setInitialValues` and in the `initialValues` prop, you can use the `initialValues={initialValues}` for the `Form` component.

(You can check detailed implementation at this codesandbox fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-23-1-forked-7i0rw0?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, but the form does not work with the dynamic form, can you please try it with a dynamic form ?